# Angular $resource PUT 400 Bad Request ($resolve and $promise get sent)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, resources, bad-request

I have the following service (with removed variables):

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('Employee', function($resource) {
        return $resource("https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/:dbName/collections/:collectionName/:id",
        {apiKey: apiKey, dbName: dbName, collectionName: collectionName},
        { update: { method: 'PUT' } });
});
```

I have the following code in my add/edit form controller for creating/retrieving an employee:

```
if($stateParams.id === "add") {
    $scope.employee = new Employee();
} else {
    $scope.employee = Employee.get({id: $stateParams.id});
}
```

Now, on my form I have a `Save` button that has the following function attached to it:

```
if($scope.employee._id) {
    $scope.employee.$update({id:$scope.employee._id});
} else {
    $scope.employee._id = $scope.employee.jmbg;
    $scope.employee.$save();
}
```

The "Add" functionality works as expected, but when I update an existing employee I get the following error:

```
400 Bad Request - Invalid object { "_id" : "000" , "jmbg" : "000" , "name" : "Bilbo" , "surname" : "Hagins" , "email" : "bibi@bibi.com" , "$promise" : { } , "$resolved" : true} - Document field names can't start with '$' (Bad Key: '$promise')
```

Now, my `$scope.employee` really does contain these two fields, but this is the first time I encountered such an error and I've already had this functionality on other projects (even one which uses the same MongoLab API for the backend and as far as I can tell there isn't any difference in the code from that other project and this one).

Also note that there is no configuration of any kind in my angular app.

Comment: Maybe you are mixing versions of Angular and Angular Resource. Before 1.3 all properties starting with `$` have not been sent to the server by Angular. Now the resource service has to remove those properties itself.

Comment: May be you are missing id in params {apiKey: apiKey, dbName: dbName, collectionName: collectionName} , id is required when updating record with $update

Comment: @zeroflagL that was it, I had angular-resource 1.2.x instead of the 1.4.x...

Answer (score 0):

When executing a PUT request, angularjs automatically adds `$promise`, and `$resolved`.

So, at the end point you should make sure to remove those attributes,

like the following example, using express's router.

`router.route('/contact/:id').put(function(req, res) {
    var contact = req.body;
    delete contact.$promise;
    delete contact.$resolved;
    // update the database
});`

But not sure about why angularjs adds `$promise` and `$resolved` on a PUT request.